# How to re-format an XML file in Phpstorm?

Tags: xml, phpstorm

I'm using Phpstorm and I have some XML file that is a single line only but contains a lot of (nested) elements. Just a common XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response><status><version>4.2</version><code>0</code><message>Success</message></status><songs><song>...
```

([gist of the full XML](https://gist.github.com/4426953)).

Having that file opened, I want to re-format it with indenting.

I have tried using *Reformat Code...* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) but it didn't change anything. I also reviewed the XML Code-Style Settings, but I don't see anything standing in the way.

Isn't it possible for Phpstorm to re-format an XML file to indent nested XML elements?

Something into the direction like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <status>
    <version>4.2</version>
    <code>0</code>
    <message>Success</message>
  </status>
  <songs>
    <song>
      ...
```

Comment: Follow up Q: Does PHPStorm have a node editor like eclipse or netbeans? Something like a design mode seen here http://i.imgur.com/MHYFJJ5.png

Comment: Anybody knows what's the command to do the opposite (i.e. put a indented XML in one single line) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Works for me (tried on full XML, not snippet) -- it took about 5-7 seconds to do .. but did it properly (PhpStorm v6 EAP build 124.373).

Most likely it's your settings (**Code Style | XML | Other**): maybe you have *"Keep line breaks"* option checked or similar option?

Comment: It was the "or similar" part for me, in concrete the *Keep white spaces* setting on the *Other* tab for XML. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: My "keep white space setting" was off already, but after turning it on and off again, this worked for me.